# Is there a PHP script that will scan files on my server and tell me when/if one changes?

Tags: php, security, file, userscripts

A few months ago I saw a PHP script built to detect malware injections in files.  Basically the script watched for any files on the server to change or for their contents to change, and then emailed an admin if the contents changed.  I haven't been able to locate a script that does this but I need one.

Does anyone know of a program like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Such a script might as well be useless - the malicious user could simply modify it to pretend no scripts have changed. It is security by obscurity.

Comment: It is. OTOH weak security might be better than no security.

Comment: I think it uses a hash to make sure it hasn't been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Intrusion Detection System like OSSEC

Answer (score 0):

It's not a PHP script, but you're probably looking for something like the [famd](http://linuxmanpages.com/man8/famd.8.php) package. Possibly used with http://php.net/manual/en/book.fam.php, however, at http://www.php.net/manual/en/fam.installation.php it states:

> This extension is considered unmaintained and dead.

... so I don't know what the current alternatives are.